# Can we add MySQL Indexes without the server and client?

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

I was given access to a cluster today along with a front-end. The person who gave me access tells me I cannot start anything on the front-end and that I should submit everything as a job. Now I have no idea what that means but I'm thinking that I am not supposed to start MySQL on the front-end. If that is the case, how can I even use the database?

Is there a way I can add indexes without using the client-server? Or is it even possible to use a database in a cluster setup where I can only submit jobs?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the person means that the client is actually executed as a "job". you might want to find out how they program the cluster.

Comment: Thank You. It is through some system called PBS. Ok so if I execute my client as a job, how would I interact with it? In addition, where would I start the server then?

Comment: I once had a similar situation, we used a supercomputer on time-slots. So, we would write a bash script that would trigger multiple other programs in a way that makes maximum use of the supercomputer. Your system might have something similar!